# «Сказала чудненький очкарик-лаборантка» — правильно ли согласован род?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, род, поэзия

> Но — стал прощать... Тревожная примета!
> И мне уже на выступленье где-то
> **Сказала чудненький очкарик-лаборантка,**
> Что я смотрю на вещи либерально.
> [Евгений Евтушенко. Давайте, мальчики!](https://books.google.ee/books?id=XMrpDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT22&lpg=PT22&dq=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C...%20%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0!&source=bl&ots=WF_Y2Y-4FH&sig=ACfU3U1eevqSKlVNkQ26QA8gJJO0uATJdw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLupSJ3_7vAhVVEncKHTqOD2kQ6AEwBnoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%BE%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C...%20%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0!&f=false)

Хотелось бы понять: правильно ли в предложении согласован род?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким правилом руководствовался поэт? Есть ли особенности?

Comment: Скорее здесь играет порядок слов: определение согласовано с ближайшем словом.

Comment: У Розенталя в §192. Определение при существительном, имеющем при себе приложение есть пункт: Оказывает влияние и порядок частей, например: Ферапонтов был толстый... мужик, с толстыми губами, ***с толстой шишкой-носом***... (Л. Толстой).

Comment: Определение согласовано с приложением "шишка". то же и у нас: определение согласовано с приложением: очкарик.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае согласование со словом "лаборантка". Надо сказать, что это разговорный стиль.

Вот правило.

> Парные образования, принятые в нейтральных стилях речи

Параллельные названия для обозначения лиц женского пола закрепились в тех случаях, когда данная специальность (профессия, род занятий и т. д.) в равной мере связана и с женским и с мужским трудом, например: акушер – акушерка, лаборант – лаборантка, летчик – летчица, преподаватель – преподавательница, продавец – продавщица, студент – студентка, учитель – учительница и мн. др. То же в области искусства, спорта, при обозначении лиц по их отношению к общественной организации и т. д.: артист – артистка, комсомолец – комсомолка, писатель – писательница, спортсмен – спортсменка.
Однако, несмотря на свободное образование подобных названий в форме женского рода, они используются не во всех стилях речи. Так, в официально-деловом стиле предпочтительно сохранять форму мужского рода, **когда речь идет о номенклатурном наименовании должности; ср. в документе-справке: «А. В. Петрова работает лаборантом на кафедре физики» (в обиходной речи – лаборантка Петрова);** «Л. И. Николаева является преподавателем английского языка» (в обиходной речи – преподавательница Николаева). Ср. бытовое: **заведующая отделом Никитина и официальное: управляющий трестом Никитина.**
См.[Автор Петрова, или Названия «неженских» профессий](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89)

Дополнение

У Розенталя в §192. Определение при существительном, имеющем при себе приложение есть пункт: Оказывает влияние и порядок частей, например: Ферапонтов был толстый... мужик, с толстыми губами, с **толстой шишкой-носом...** (Л. Толстой).

Comment: А с чем ( или с кем ) согласовать "чудненький"?

Comment: Возможно, таким разнобоем Поэт хотел передать свою потерю сосредоточенности от вида этого существа; безобиднее было бы так:
- А вы примите антидепрессант, -
сказала чудная очкарка-лаборант :)

Comment: "Очкарки" не бывает. "Сказала чудная очкарик-лаборантка" – вот так надо.

Answer (score 4):

**Вариант 1.   Не чудненький, а чудненькая**

Тогда: **Сказала чудненькая очкарик-лаборантка.** Здесь очкарик ― это приложение, лаборантка ― определяемое слово, с которым и согласуется определение "чудненькая" и сказуемое "сказала".

Для сохранения размера стиха подходит вариант "сказала чУдная очкарик-лаборантка", но не подходит по смыслу.

**Вариант 2. Но есть еще решение:** "чудненький очкарик" можно рассматривать как единое определение к существительному "лаборантка": Сказала (чудненький очкарик)-лаборантка. **Вероятно, именно на такое прочтение и рассчитывал поэт.**

Comment: Воспринимается так: лаборантка выглядит как "чудненький очкарик", есть в ней что-то мальчишеское.

Comment: Думаю, что не обязательно она похожа на мальчика,  хотя внешность представляется  своеобразной: худенькая, большие очки, короткая стрижка.  Просто сущ. "очкарик" не имеет  пары для женского рода. Можно сказать: Наша лаборантка - такой чудненький очкарик.

Answer (score 2):

У Евтушенко нарушен стандартный порядок слов. Приложение "очкарик" должно следовать за определяемым словом - и тогда все становится на место: "Сказала чудненькая лаборантка-очкарик."

У [Лопатина в § 120](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65#pp65) сказано, что через дефис пишутся "сочетания с однословными **приложениями, следующими за определяемым словом**" (писатель-эмигрант, студент-медик), а **приложения, предшествующие определяемому слову**, "носят оценочный характер" (красавица-дочка, умница-сын).

Мне кажется, по стандарту определение (прилагательное) должно относится к определяемому слову из дефисной пары. Такие построения, как "большая умниица-сын" должны заменяться на "сын - большая умница", а "чудненький очкарик-лаборантка"  - на "лаборантка - чудненький очкарик".

А все остальное - "серая" область, где у разных людей могут быть разные мнения о том, что правильно, а что - нет.

Comment: Вы предлагаете заменить "очкарик-лаборантка" на "лаборантка-очкарик"? Здесь играет роль порядок слов: определение согласовано с ближайшем словом. У Розенталя это оговаривается.

Comment: @М_Г К вопросу о ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ: До лопатинской реформы писали так: Тут выдался ... частый осинник, и в нём стоял РОГАТЫЙ великан лось. [М. М. Пришвин. Кладовая солнца (1945)]  По-моему, неплохо: определение + приложение перед определяемым словом.  Сделаем замену:  в нём стоял рогатый большой лось. Раньше орфография отражала грамматику, а теперь это длинный перечень не очень ясных правил. Поэтому с лопатинскими дефисными парами  вида лучше никаких экспериментов не проводить.

Answer (score 2):

> Хотелось бы понять: правильно ли в предложении согласован род?
>   Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким правилом руководствовался поэт? Есть ли
>   особенности?

Это ошибка. Не знаю, случайная или намеренная, но скорее всего - второе. Евтушенко (Царствие небесное!) вполне владеет грамматикой, чтобы непреднамеренно такое не написать - и не заметить потом. Скорее всего, автор слово "чудненький" умышленно согласовывает со словом "очкарик", подчеркивая смысловую нагрузку.

Что по строгим правилам невозможно совершенно, так это "сказала" и "чудненький" - при одном и том же подлежащем. Можете взять это за правило, согласование все-таки идет или последовательно и регулярно, или никак. Думаю, Евтушенко понимает это не хуже нас с вами. Так что полагаю - грамматический эрратив, и вполне продуманный.

Нормативно: ***"сказала чудненькая"***

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова есть хорошее правило в таких случаях случаях использовать настоящее время (если автор не о себе). Поэтому "Ваш покорный слуга писал", но "Евтушенко пишет" - это дань уважения авторам и их работам, которые не устаревают. В научной среде считается хорошим тоном. Возможно, его не всегда уместно применять, но в моем посте, дкмаю, вполне.

Comment: "Это ошибка", "Что по строгим правилам невозможно совершенно, так это "сказала" и "чудненький" - при одном и том же подлежащем" -- Но ведь между строгими правилами и ошибкой есть еще зона допустимого (в особенности в разговорной речи). Существует смысловое (а не грамматическое) согласование. Например: "Наш семейный врач сказала."

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно рассматривать более специфический случай, а именно дефисные пары (определяемое слово - приложение)

Comment: @М_Г *Но ведь между строгими правилами и ошибкой* - Я не совсем понимаю, что именно в моем тексте вызвало к жизни эту сентенцию. В любом случае это весьма спорное суждение, но без понимания, к чему вы хотите его привязать, я бы не хотел его разбирать. Грамматика не позволяет таких вольностей. Грамматический род дефисного сочетания определяется одним словом, а не обоими - в зависимости от прихоти говорящего. Другое дело, что в лингвистике существует такое понятие, как умышленное нарушение нормы (эрратив). Но это совсем не то, о чем можно сказать "между нормой и ошибкой".

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно, прилагательное надо согласовывать со словом "лаборантка". Например, "сказала чудная очкарик-лаборантка".

Answer (score 0):

Существует правило согласования прилагательных по роду существительного, а глаголов по полу лица, о котором идëт речь:
"Умелый машинист электропоезда Галина Петровна прекрасно вписалась в поворот".
"Опытная машинистка Сергей Петрович закончил печатать статью".
"Наш участковый врач Светлана Степановна выписала рецепт и ушла".
Что касается согласования слов, пишущихся через дефис, в ситуации, когда обе части слова склоняются, согласование происходит по первой части: "У стены стоял синий диван-кровать".
"Мы подошли к новому дивану-кровати".
Так что в приведëнном примере согласование соответствует правилам.